# How to generate / split data randomly in PySpark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

The following line of Scala code in Apache Spark will split data randomly across 8 partition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand


df
.repartition(8, col("person_country"), rand)
.write
.partitionBy("person_country")
.csv(outputPath)
```

Can someone show me how to do the equivalent with PySpark? I have attempted it myself with the following code, but it fails

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand
df\
  .repartition(8, col("person_country"), rand)\
  .write.partitionBy("person_country")\
  .format('csv').mode('Overwrite')\
  .save("outputPath")
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am thinking: whats is the error? ;)

Comment: actaully, the code is ```df\
  .repartition(5)\
  .write\
  .partitionBy("person_country", rand)\
  .format('csv').mode('Overwrite')\
  .save("outputPath")``` and the error is AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Comment: `repartition(8, col("person_country"), rand())` with parenthesis after rand maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

`repartition(8, col("person_country"), rand())` with parenthesis after rand